# Asynchronous T-SQL triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asynchronous, ssms, sqlclr

Suppose you have the the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.testwait1 (id INT)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.testwait2 (id INT)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER testwait1t ON dbo.testwait1
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testwait2 (id)
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER testwait2t ON dbo.testwait2
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

    SELECT *
    FROM inserted
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.testwait1 (id)
SELECT 1

SELECT *
FROM dbo.testwait1

SELECT *
FROM dbo.testwait2
```

Without using the SQL Service Broker queue, how would you accomplish asynchronous INSERT into the dbo.testwait2 table? After all, you don't want to actually wait the full 10 seconds. Is there a way to use the SQL CLR to perform this operation? If so, could some sample code be provided (specifically what sets the CLR to be async)?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? What does the WAITFOR stand for?

Comment: I've updated the question. The WAITFOR is an example of some long running query/complex logic.

Comment: Read up on service broker (or explain why you are discarding it as a solution). Examples: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/intro-to-service-broker and http://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/configuring-service-broker